# -bash: jspm: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, jspm

I am trying to npm install JSPM, so that I can run jspm init, for instance.

```
npm install -g jspm
```

is unfortunately not enabling the jspm cli.

```
npm install jspm --save-dev
```

in project root, isn't doing the trick either.

```
node -v = v6.2.1
npm -v = 3.9.3
echo $PATH = /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

The error

```
-bash: jspm: command not found
```

occurs after running jspm init, or jspm.

OS: OS X El Capitan version 10.11.3

Symlink when running an
npm install -g jspm

```
/Users/user/.npm-packages/bin/jspm -> /Users/user/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/jspm/jspm.js
/Users/user/.npm-packages/lib
```

My thanks as always :)

Comment: in which step you getting the error `-bash: jspm: command not found`?

Comment: after running jspm init, and after all of them.

Comment: but no where in question you mentioned `jspm init`

Comment: Updated, thank you :)

Comment: is `npm install ...` command successful? Or did it show any error?

Comment: npm install is successful

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a downvote. If you have a reason why please tell me so I can edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end after thinking through the answer here is what I did to solve this problem.

**ONE**

I searched around and found that my $PATH variable was located here ~/.profile

so running

```
emacs ~/.profile
```

I was able to edit path directly from my terminal(Iterm).

**TWO**

I made sure to remove any duplicate filepaths and to make sure that all default paths went first, so that my local paths would override them. It ended up looking like this

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

**THREE**

In addition, I realized that if any path was missing it would be the

```
/Users/user/.npm-packages/bin
```

filepath. 
I added it, where user would be your name. In my case charlie, so

```
/Users/charlie/.npm-packages/bin.
```

That did it, running jspm worked as expected. NOICE!

**FINAL $PATH**

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/charlie/.npm-packages/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add it to your environment variables.

In **windows** add the following line on your ***path*** environment variables:

```
%appdata%\npm
```

In **OS X** it might be something like (I am not sure about the exact syntax but it might give you some direction):

```
~/.bash_profile
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Comment: In addition, I am going to look at the duplicates in my path, in addition to local being default and usr/bin default overriding local. This article to understanding paths(especially on mac), is helpful https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/

Comment: Another resource that helps for this, allowing one to find actual files on mac where $PATH is concatenated from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832770/where-is-the-default-terminal-path-located-on-mac

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777); also, you probably mean OS X, not iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by running the installation as sudo:

`npm install jspm -g`

A lot of the other posts had elaborate workarounds involving NVM, editing permissions on bash files, etc. but I'm too busy and just need this to work.