# How to bundle an executable jar file to be run as a cli command on macOS with jpackage (or similar tools)?

Tags: macos, kotlin, command-line-interface, picocli

I have written a command line tool using picocli and Kotlin. Then I compiled it to an executable uber jar and it actually works as a standalone application by running

```
java -jar MyJarFile.jar [cli options and parameters]
```

But how do I bundle it so that I can distribute it on Mac, so that I can run it as

```
mycommand [cli options and parameters]
```

I know I can use jpackage, I used it and generated a .pkg file that installed the app on my Mac in the /Applications folder. I guess there is a file that i have to put in a folder that is in the PATH in order to use it as a command line tool. How do I "automate" the process? Is jpackage the right tool?

Wrapping up, what I want to do is to bundle my executable jar so that when the installation process on Mac finishes the user can write

```
mycommand [cli options and parameters]
```

Comment: With [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/) you can build a `pkg` with a custom post-installation script

Comment: your link is not working... and then, what should the postinstall script do? This is my very first macOS app, I don't even know how the whole thing works

Comment: Oops! Here is the correct link: http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html
With this tool, you may configure the installation path (by the way, jpackage can do this as well via `--install-dir` key) and a post-script should [add it to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently).
Alternatively, you may try to install it into a directory which is [in PATH by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832770/where-is-the-default-terminal-path-located-on-mac) (like `usr/local/bin` for instance), so no post-scripts needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picocli documentation has a [list of options](https://picocli.info/#_packaging_your_application) for packaging your application. (Suggestions for additional options are welcome.)

One of these options that deserves a special mention is [creating a native image](https://picocli.info/#_graalvm_native_image) with [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/).

Comment: I ended up creating a formula on Homebrew, but that still depends on the machine having java, so I'll give a try to this!